# pgfmathparse Not Working

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

Can somebody help me with the following code? I am trying to retrieve a value but it gives me an error.

I want to do some mathematical operations on \CPAN using pgfmathparse but it gives me an issue.

```
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}% set a "random" seed based on time
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{myarray}{{semianually}{daily}{anually}{monthly}{quarterly}}

\newcommand{\CompoundPeriod}[1]
{
  \edef\mytemp{{#1}}
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{daily}{365}{ }
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{semianually}{2}{ }
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{quarterly}{4}{ }
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{monthly}{12}{ }
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{anually}{1}{ }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathrandomitem{\CPA}{myarray}

\newcommand{\CPAN}{\CompoundPeriod{\CPA}}

\pgfmathparse{\CPAN+2} 

\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

It gives me an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The definition of `\CompoundPeriod` makes it unfit for being used in `\pgfmathparse`.

Comment: How should I change the definition of \CompoundPeriod to make it fit for \pgfmathparse?

Answer (score 1):

`\pgfmathparse` fully-expands it's argument, similar to `\edef`. So you can't use non-expandable commands in the argument, but your `\CompoundPeriod` uses `\edef` and `\ifstrequal` which are not expandable.

So you have to avoid using these. If you use pdfTeX you can use `\pdfstrcmp` to build an expandable `\ifstrequal` which also expands it's arguments, so you do not need `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}% set a "random" seed based on time
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{myarray}{{semianually}{daily}{anually}{monthly}{quarterly}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifexpstrequal[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0 
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\CompoundPeriod}[1]{
  \ifexpstrequal{#1}{daily}{365}{ }
  \ifexpstrequal{#1}{semianually}{2}{ }
  \ifexpstrequal{#1}{quarterly}{4}{ }
  \ifexpstrequal{#1}{monthly}{12}{ }
  \ifexpstrequal{#1}{anually}{1}{ }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathrandomitem{\CPA}{myarray}

\newcommand{\CPAN}{\CompoundPeriod{\CPA}}

\pgfmathparse{\CPAN+2} 

\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

Comment: So many spaces…

Comment: @egreg I tried to keep `\CompoundPeriod` as similar to the version from the question as possible so I didn't delete the spaces, but `\ifexpstrequal` does not introduce any additional spaces AFAICT.

Comment: It actually adds 5 whitespace chars.

Comment: @percusse Where are they added?

Comment: You have to add `%` to every line in `\ifexpstrequal`

Comment: @percusse Have you tested this? The last four lines end with command sequences, they gobble the space. The first line needs the space to delimit the `\ifnum`. If I test for example with `\typeout{|\ifexpstrequal{a}{a}{}{}|}`, there are no spaces visible.